# Is binary to decimal conversion rounded? how?

Tags: c, binary, printf, double, decimal

Got to transform a binary number to decimal for recoding printf (no lib or functions allowed except malloc and write). i'm doing my calculs on char *, so it can't overflow. But when i hit a certain size, my result differ from a online binary converter, and i noticed that the binary converter keep always only 20 digits.

for exemple :

- binary : 1.11111111111111111111111111
- binary converter = 1.99999998509883880615,
- my o converter == 1.99799896499882880605234375,

I guess the online converter keep the result rounded in an unsigned long long, but i don't understand how this rounding is calculated.

Do you have any clues?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ft_binary_pow(char *tmp, int i)
{
    int j;
    int div;
    int remnant;

    j = 0;
    remnant = 0;
    tmp[0] = '1';
    tmp.sign = 0;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        while (isdigit(tmp[j]) || remnant != 0)
        {
            if (tmp[j])
                div = ((tmp[j] - '0') * 10) / 2;
            else
                div = 0;
            tmp[j] = ((div / 10) + remnant) + '0';
            remnant = div % 10;
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i--;
    }
    return (tmp);
}

char  *ft_add_tmp(char *ret, char *tmp)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int add;
    int remnant;

    i = strlen(tmp);
    add = 0;
    remnant = 0;
    while (--i >= 0)
    {
        if (!ret[i])
            add = tmp[i] - '0';
        else
            add = (ret[i] - '0') + (tmp[i] - '0');
        if ((add % 10 + remnant) < 10)
            ret[i] = (add % 10 + remnant) + '0';
        else
            ret[i] = '0';
        remnant = add / 10 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return (ret);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char    *lol = "11111111111111111111111111";
    char    *ret;
    char    *tmp;

    if (!(ret = (char *)calloc(340, sizeof(char))))
        return (0);
    i = 0;
    ret[0] = '1';
    while (lol[i])
    {
        if (lol[i] == '1')
        {
            if (!(tmp = (char *)calloc(50, sizeof(char))))
            return (0);
            tmp = ft_binary_pow(tmp, i + 1);
            ret = ft_add_tmp(ret, tmp);
            free(tmp);
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("ret = %s\n", ret);
    return (0);
}
```

Edited for more readable code

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `my o converter` is wrong - quite wrong.  Post its code.  Likely an integer overflow.

Comment: like i said, i'm using char * to do my calculations, maximum possible number on each calcul is 19, so int overflow can't be a problem. But i'm adding code right now :)

Comment: In English, what is a "calcul"?  French for "calculation"?

Comment: yes, sorry ˆˆ and i don't understand why the post is closed? i just tried to edit it with my code

Comment: We cannot tell you why your code is wrong without seeing your code. _"i'm using char * to do my calculations"_ tells us nothing.  It is certainly not any kind of reassurance that your code is correct.

Comment: i know, i tried to add my code, but SO closed my post - don't know why - and now i can't...

Comment: Do you see it now?

Comment: I have voted to re-open, but it needs more votes.

Comment: Your code vs an on-line calculator that has probably been tested and used by thousands - Occam's razor suggests that no, you cannot assume yours is more precise.  Better to show some realistic humility and ask why your code is in error.  Your result is about as accurate as if you'd used only 10 binary digits - That can be checked in Excel - `1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + ...`

Comment: I understand that my post might feel like i'm saying my code is better than the one used for the conversion, but it isn't what i'm trying to say here. I'm asking if the converter store the result on an unsigned long long with some rounding. I'm saying that because when you convert large binary number, the result (1.the_result) is always in the same precision (20 digits), and seems to be rounded.

Comment: How can we tell how someone else's unseen code works?  We can only discuss your code here.  That said the on-line calculator is in JavaScript and is in fact there for all to see by page inspection.  Java types are dynamic however, so there is no "unsigned long long" -  I looked at the code and it is implemented using `BigNumber.js` which does the heavy lifting.

Comment: Sure, but for 1.11111111111111111 the result is 21 digits, as for 1.1111111111111111111111111111. so i guess it use dtoa or something like that, which use rounding. so i was asking this point. Anyway i will reopen a post i guess

Comment: Posted code prints "ret = 199799896499882880605234375", not "1.99799896499882880605234375".  Where is your `'.'` coming from?

Comment: because i'm transforming the fraction part on a double which is 1.the_binary. you just have to assume that there's a '.' after the first digit.

Comment: So the "lol = "11111111111111111111111111";" is  really to be interpreted as "1.11111111111111111111111111" (base 2) and the output "199799896499882880605234375" is really "1.99799896499882880605234375" (base 10)?

Comment: yes. sorry, it's not clear here! you should replace the lol = 111111... with less 1, like lol = "1111" , and compare it with 1.1111, the conversion is correct at this level

Comment: It is of course mathematically absurd to convert to more decimal digits that you have binary digits.  The place value of the 20th decimal place is about 9.56E13 times _smaller_ that that of the 20th binary place.  20 binary digits give the same _precision_ as log10(2^20) = ~6 decimal digits.  You could get sufficiently accurate result using `float` and certainly `double` with much simpler code.

Comment: ... my error you have 26 binary digits so log10(2^26) = ~8 digits - so `double` - good for 15 significant digits.

Comment: If do cumulative addition in double, I get 1.999999970197678, the same in Excel is 1.99999997019767, but also in Excel directly calculating the correct value by (2^26-1)*2^-26+1, gives 1.99999998509883 which agrees with the online calculator in so far as the 15 digit precision allows.  But the point is they all resolve to 1.9999999 when presented to only the 8 digits of precision that 26 binary digits warrants - so they are all correct.  Your result is in error by about 0.1%.

Comment: @Clifford Note: OP's coding error can also manifest itself in worst ways than 0.1%.  `"0001101"` leads to a 1% error.  Perhaps other more so.

Answer (score 0):

Code fails even with `lol = "111111111"`.

Code fails in `ft_add_tmp()` to handle a carry (overflow) into the next most significant digit.

```
else {
  ret.decimal[i] = '0';
  // add something like this and then also prorogate carry as needed to higher digits
  ret.decimal[i-1]++;  
}
```

Suggested correction and simplification:

```
char* ft_add_tmp(char *ret, const char *tmp) {
  size_t i = strlen(tmp);
  unsigned carry = 0;
  while (i-- > 0) {
    unsigned sum = ret[i] ? ret[i] - '0' : 0;
    sum += tmp[i] - '0' + carry;
    ret[i] = sum % 10 + '0';
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  assert(carry == 0);
  return (ret);
}
```

Comment: dude, thank you so much, i thought it was a rouding because only one digit was wrong... now my function is way more precise :D

Comment: @CanardWcs Tip: Careful when debugging and cutting off lines of investigations with conclusions like "so it can't overflow."